# Update query with LIMIT ( setMaxResults ) in doctrine2 using createQueryBuilder not working

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, dql

I have the following code

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('cs')
        ->update()
        ->set('cs.is_active', 1)
        ->where('cs.reward_coupon = :reward_coupon')
        ->setMaxResults($limit)
        ->setParameter('reward_coupon', $rewardCoupon);
$qb->getQuery()->execute();
```

This doesn’t apply the LIMIT in the resultant query.

Answer (score 3):

setMaxResult() has to be your last Doctrine statement in order to properly works

example :

```
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('cs')
    ->update()
    ->set('cs.is_active', 1)
    ->where('cs.reward_coupon = :reward_coupon')
    ->setParameter('reward_coupon', $rewardCoupon)
    ->setMaxResults($limit);


     return $qb->getQuery()->execute();
```

Answer (score -1):

I think that this may help

```
$limit=50;
$i=0;
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('cs')
->update()
->set('cs.is_active', 1)
->where('cs.reward_coupon = :reward_coupon')
->setParameter('reward_coupon', $rewardCoupon)
->setFirstResult($i)
->setMaxResults($limit);
$qb->getQuery()->execute();
```

Comment: You cannot set a starting index for LIMIT when used in an UPDATE statement.